# If $\int^2_0 g(x) dx = 4$, then solve $\int^4_0 \left(4\cdot g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + ax\right)\,dx = 64$ for $a$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

So here is the question:

> Given that $$\int^2_0 g(x) dx = 4$$
> solve for $a$:
> $$\int^4_0 \left(4\cdot g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + ax\right)\,dx = 64$$

Here is where I am up to:

$$\begin{align}
\int^4_0 \left(4\cdot g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) +ax\right)\, dx = 64 \tag1 \\[1em]
\int^4_0 4\cdot g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\,dx + \int^4_0ax\,dx =64 \tag2 \\[1em]
4\int^4_0 g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\,dx + a\int^4_0x\,dx =64 \tag3\\[1em]
4\int^4_0 g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\,dx + 8a = 64 \tag4
\end{align}$$

I do not what to do with the $g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ part. Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: sub $x/2=t {}{}$

Comment: How can I sub in for $t$ if I am integrating with respect to $x$???

Comment: If you do not already know about substitution in integrals, then this problem is probably too hard for you.

Comment: @GEdgar yeah, I do not know substitution in integrals as we do not focus on it in my subject however, this question came in one of the trial exams, which means there must be another way? I resorted to looking at a dilated graph for an arbitrary function, $g(x)$ to figure out any change in the area but was still unsure.

Comment: HINT: One linear solution to $g(x)$ is $2x$

Comment: One of the things substitution in integrals can do for you is to dilate a graph. If you understand how to dilate a graph in the $x$ direction then you should be fine.

Comment: @LogLogLogLogx I am not following

Comment: @DavidK I know how to dilate a graph but not substitution

Comment: Yes the limits of the integral **need** to be different or you are lost. Since you only know the integral between the limits $0$ and $2,$ the only way you'll be able to know the integral after dilation is if the new limits are at whatever place the dilation takes the lines $x=0$ and $x=2$ to. If that's where the new limits are, the shape under the graph will be the exact same shape except that it is expanded by a horizontal factor, and you can make some inference about how much larger it is. Any other limits will give you an unknown new shape and you know nothing about its area.

Comment: So you mean: $\frac{x}{2} = 0$ and $\frac{x}{2} = 2$

Comment: I would recommend to not bother yourself and learn integration by substitution. You can find a lot of articles on the internet. After that, the problem will be a cakewalk.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^44g(x/2)+ax\,dx$$
now let $u=x/2\Rightarrow dx=2du$ so:
$$2\int_0^24g(u)+2au\,du$$
$$=8\int_0^2g(u)\,du+4a\int_0^2u\,du$$
can you take it from here?

Comment: Everything is ok,  but why did you change the limits of the integrals?

Comment: @ShootingStars that is a result of changing the variable for $x$ to $u$